# error: constructor Player in class Player cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: types, constructor, composition

whenever I compile my code, I receive the following errors:

> error: constructor Player in class Player cannot be applied to given types;

but it doesn't list any types. The code in question is

```
public class Team {
private String name;
public Player players[];
public Player temp;

public Team(String inputname, Player players[]) {

    inputname = name;
    this.players = new Player [players.length];
    for( int k=0 ; k<players.length ; k++ )
        this.players[k] = new Player(players[k]); //This is the line with errors.

}
```

The Player class is found below:

```
public class Player {

public String[] name;

public Player(String inputname) {

    name = inputname.split(" ");

}}
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong here? If it helps, on the line with errors, players[k] would be a name-like string, such as "Billy Bob."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
players[k]
```

is of type Player, and your constructor is expecting String:

```
public Player(String inputname)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Revised my code to create a Player object from Strings, and it works just fine now.

Answer (score 2):

The error is that the constructor of Player (`public Player(String inputname)`) expects a string, but you are trying to pass it a Player object (the k'th element of the array `players`).

The fix is to write `this.players[k] = new Player(inputName);`

Thus passing the constructor a string, and storing the constructed object in the k'th index of the array `players`

Answer (score 0):

```
class CricketPlayer extends Player
{
    CricketPlayer(String var)
    {
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        System.out.println("Play Cricket:-" + getName());
    }
}
```