# constructor in class cannot applied to given types

Tags: java, web-services

I have problem with this `constructor TblPemohon in class entity.TblPemohon cannot applied to given types`.

I'm using Netbeans 7.0.1

The code for `entity.TblProblem`:

```
public class TblPemohon {
    private String KtpPemohon;
    private String NamaDepanPemohon;
    private String NamaBelakangPemohon;
    private String TempatLahirPemohon;
    private String TanggalLahirPemohon;
    private String JenisKelamin;
    private String AgamaPemohon;
    private String StatusPerkawinan;
    private String PekerjaanPemohon;
    private String NamaJalanPemohon;
    private String NoAlamatPemohon;
    private String RtPemohon;
    private String RwPemohon;
    private String KelurahanPemohon;
    private String KecamatanPemohon;
    private String KabupatenPemohon;
    private String ProvinsiPemohon;
    private String KodePosPemohon;
    private String TelpPemohon;
    private String KewarganegaraanPemohon;

    private String errorCode;

    public TblPemohon() {

    }

    public String getKtpPemohon() {
        return KtpPemohon;
    }

    public void setKtpPemohon(String KtpPemohon) {
        this.KtpPemohon = KtpPemohon;
    }

    public String getNamaDepanPemohon() {
        return NamaDepanPemohon;
    }

    public void setNamaDepanPemohon(String NamaDepanPemohon) {
        this.NamaDepanPemohon = NamaDepanPemohon;
    }

    public String getNamaBelakangPemohon() {
        return NamaBelakangPemohon;
    }

    public void setNamaBelakangPemohon(String NamaBelakangPemohon) {
        this.NamaBelakangPemohon = NamaBelakangPemohon;
    }

    public String getTempatLahirPemohon() {
        return TempatLahirPemohon;
    }

    public void setTempatLahirPemohon(String TempatLahirPemohon) {
        this.TempatLahirPemohon = TempatLahirPemohon;
    }

    public String getTanggalLahirPemohon() {
        return TanggalLahirPemohon;
    }

    public void setTanggalLahirPemohon(String TanggalLahirPemohon) {
        this.TanggalLahirPemohon = TanggalLahirPemohon;
    }

    public String getJenisKelamin() {
        return JenisKelamin;
    }

    public void setJenisKelamin(String JenisKelamin) {
        this.JenisKelamin = JenisKelamin;
    }

    public String getAgamaPemohon() {
        return AgamaPemohon;
    }

    public void setAgamaPemohon(String AgamaPemohon) {
        this.AgamaPemohon = AgamaPemohon;
    }

    public String getStatusPerkawinan() {
        return StatusPerkawinan;
    }

    public void setStatusPerkawinan(String StatusPerkawinan) {
        this.StatusPerkawinan = StatusPerkawinan;
    }

    public String getPekerjaanPemohon() {
        return PekerjaanPemohon;
    }

    public void setPekerjaanPemohon(String PekerjaanPemohon) {
        this.PekerjaanPemohon = PekerjaanPemohon;
    }

    public String getNamaJalanPemohon() {
        return NamaJalanPemohon;
    }

    public void setNamaJalanPemohon(String NamaJalanPemohon) {
        this.NamaJalanPemohon = NamaJalanPemohon;
    }

    public String getNoAlamatPemohon() {
        return NoAlamatPemohon;
    }

    public void setNoAlamatPemohon(String NoAlamatPemohon) {
        this.NoAlamatPemohon = NoAlamatPemohon;
    }

    public String getRtPemohon() {
        return RtPemohon;
    }

    public void setRtPemohon(String RtPemohon) {
        this.RtPemohon = RtPemohon;
    }

    public String getRwPemohon() {
        return RwPemohon;
    }

    public void setRwPemohon(String RwPemohon) {
        this.RwPemohon = RwPemohon;
    }

    public String getKelurahanPemohon() {
        return KelurahanPemohon;
    }

    public void setKelurahanPemohon(String KelurahanPemohon) {
        this.KelurahanPemohon = KelurahanPemohon;
    }

    public String getKecamatanPemohon() {
        return KecamatanPemohon;
    }

    public void setKecamatanPemohon(String KecamatanPemohon) {
        this.KecamatanPemohon = KecamatanPemohon;
    }

    public String getKabupatenPemohon() {
        return KabupatenPemohon;
    }

    public void setKabupatenPemohon(String KabupatenPemohon) {
        this.KabupatenPemohon = KabupatenPemohon;
    }

    public String getProvinsiPemohon() {
        return ProvinsiPemohon;
    }

    public void setProvinsiPemohon(String ProvinsiPemohon) {
        this.ProvinsiPemohon = ProvinsiPemohon;
    }

    public String getKodePosPemohon() {
        return KodePosPemohon;
    }

    public void setKodePosPemohon(String KodePosPemohon) {
        this.KodePosPemohon = KodePosPemohon;
    }

    public String getTelpPemohon() {
        return TelpPemohon;
    }

    public void setTelpPemohon(String TelpPemohon) {
        this.TelpPemohon = TelpPemohon;
    }

    public String getKewarganegaraanPemohon() {
        return KewarganegaraanPemohon;
    }

    public void setKewarganegaraanPemohon(String KewarganegaraanPemohon) {
        this.KewarganegaraanPemohon = KewarganegaraanPemohon;
    }

    public String getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

}
```

and the code for another class which call it

```
public List<TblPemohon> getTblPemohons() {
    DataBase db = new DataBase();
    try {
        Pemohon p = new Pemohon(db.getConnection());
        return p.getTblPemohons();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        List<TblPemohon> ltp = new ArrayList<TblPemohon>();
        ltp.add(new TblPemohon(e.getMessage()));
        return ltp;
    } finally {
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line does the error occur on?

Comment: [Possibly Duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916615/error-constructor-player-in-class-player-cannot-be-applied-to-given-types)

Answer (score 2):

Your TblPemohon class only have non-argument constructor, but you tried to create it with a constructor that takes one string here:

```
ltp.add(new TblPemohon(e.getMessage()));
```

You need to either add a constructor that take one string, or use the non-argument constructor